# Material UI Autocomplete showing wrong searched value (some extra invalid results in the suggested options)

Tags: material-ui, autocomplete

```
import * as React from 'react';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import Autocomplete from '@mui/material/Autocomplete';
import Stack from '@mui/material/Stack';

const demoList = [
  { label: 'Maggie Li', value: 'Maggie.li@gmail.com' },
  {
    label: 'Rajadurai sidharta vaasan Achamthavirthan',
    value: 'Rajadurai.sidharta.vaasan.Achamthavirthan@gmail.com',
  },
  { label: 'Sumit Kumar', value: 'sk1@gmail.com' },
  { label: 'Sumit Kumar', value: 'sk2@gmail.com' },
  { label: 'Sumit Kumar', value: 'sk3@gmail.com' },
  { label: 'Indranil Basu', value: 'ib@gmail.com' },
]

export default function Playground() {
  const defaultProps = {
    options: demoList,
    getOptionLabel: (option) => option.label,
  };

  return (
    <Stack spacing={1} sx={{ width: 300 }}>
      <Autocomplete
        {...defaultProps}
        id="disable-close-on-select"
        disableCloseOnSelect
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField {...params} label="disableCloseOnSelect" variant="standard" />
        )}
      />
    </Stack>
  );
}
```

When i search for [image] , it shows irrelevent results in the drop options.

Any insights / clues ?

I expect only options that are matching the keyed in text should appear.

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue - looks like if key is not unique in the list of options then the console throws this warning. Also the search gets garbled. If the names (keys) are unique then this issue of bad search doesn't happen.
[image]

Further read : https://lockstep.io/blog/debugging-lesson-well-learned-fixing-material-ui-autocomplete-search/